# How to format sql in exec statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2008-r2, exec

When I run the following code

```
declare @startDT datetime
declare @endDT datetime
set @startDT = '2014-09-18 09:28:15.650'
set @endDT = N'2014-09-18 09:28:15.650'

declare @tstamp datetime
set @tstamp = '05/06/2014  15:08:00'

exec('if ' + @startDT + ' <= ' + @tstamp + '
begin
select ''less than''
end
else
begin
select ''greater than''
end')
```

I get the below error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near '18'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'else'.
```

However when I remove the exec it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `select ''less than''`. Select from where (no table specified)? I think you meant to use print there.

Comment: Hi, It should just print the less than or greater than. It works if I don't use exec. Also you are right I can also use print. However print will print the text in messages(tab) when I execute the script and not in results(tab).

Comment: Then change the query to `select ''less than'' from dual`

Comment: IS it not oracle syntax. I do not have a table called dual. What is dual?

Comment: I just tried this and it works
exec('select ''works!''')

Comment: Just to let you know am using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: my apologies. I overlooked the fact that you aren't using Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to form a complete SQL query in a string, then pass that as a parameter. Accordingly the string needs the datetime values as strings until the @SQL parameter is executed. In side the @SQL then use convert(datetime...) to ensure the wanted comparison is undertaken as datetime.

```
DECLARE @sql     nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @startDT nvarchar(23)
DECLARE @endDT   nvarchar(23)

SET @startDT = N'2014-09-18 09:28:15.650'
SET @endDT   = N'2014-09-18 09:28:15.650'

DECLARE @tstamp nvarchar(23)
SET @tstamp = N'2014-05-06 15:08:00'


SET @sql = N'if convert(datetime,'''
           + @startDT
           + ''',121) <= convert(datetime,'''
           + @tstamp 
           + ''',121) begin
 select ''less than''
 end
 else
 begin
 select ''greater than''
 end'

-- SELECT @sql
-- if convert(datetime,'2014-09-18 09:28:15.650',121) <= convert(datetime,'2014-05-06 15:08:00',121) begin select 'less than' end else begin select 'greater than' end

EXEC(@SQL)
```

use `select @sql` to inspect the dynamic query string, a of which sample is contained above.

<kbd>[See this SQLFidde demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6544a/1)</kbd>

Formatted the generated string looks like this:

```
IF CONVERT(datetime, '2014-09-18 09:28:15.650', 121) <=
      CONVERT(datetime, '2014-05-06 15:08:00', 121)
BEGIN
      SELECT
            'less than'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
      SELECT
            'greater than'
END
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @startDT datetime
declare @endDT datetime
set @startDT = '2014-09-18 09:28:15.650'
set @endDT = N'2014-09-18 09:28:15.650'

declare @tstamp datetime
set @tstamp = '05/06/2014  15:08:00'

exec('if ' +'"'+ @tstamp +'"'+ ' <= ' +'"'+ @tstamp +'"'+ '
begin
select ''less than''
end
else
begin
select ''greater than''
end')
```

This happens when this function returns SQL Query with syntax error when ever you parse the sql datetime it should parse inside ''.try with this code.i modified your query.

Comment: Thanks. When I run your script I get the following error
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'May  6 2014  3:08PM'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid column name 'May  6 2014  3:08PM'.

Comment: You are right though. It was syntax error due to formatting.